# ReactJS accessing current prop state under custom window event

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

Using ReactJS to create a small reusable component; however I am stumped on accessing the current props inside a custom window event.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export const TestFun = (props) => {
  const handleClick = () =>{
    console.log(props.page);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener("click", handleClick, false)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("click", handleClick, false)
  },[])

  return(<h1>{props.page}</h1>)
}

export default function App() {
  const [page,setPage] = useState(1);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <TestFun page={page} />
      <button onClick={()=>setPage(page+1)}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When this little gem is run, it updates the props correctly on the button click but the page number remains the same in the console.

I've tried using `useRef()` but it is certain that I am not using it correctly because my results don't change.  Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction, please.

Comment: before all things, it should be setPage((prev) => prev + 1), that might fix your issue

Comment: Not sure what the difference is but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Maybe try to pass the page to your click function, I'm not sure https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-hill-gkne3w?file=/src/App.js
Looks like it's working

Comment: I did it that way just to show what was going on, but adding the click function to the useEffect dependency worked.  But I have never seen that before.  What exactly is happening by doing that?